# In C: Reading integers from a file

Tags: c, file, output

I have a function that basically read integers from a file:

```
FILE *file;

file = fopen("filename.txt", "r");
fscanf(file, "%d", &(*pn));
fscanf(file, "%d", &(*pm));
fscanf(file, "%d", &(*pmax));

printf("*pm = %d\n", *pm);
printf("*pn = %d\n", *pn);
printf("*pmax = %d\n", *pmax);
```

First I tried with the following file:

> 5 4
>
> 128

My output was correct, as I wanted:

```
*pm = 4
*pn = 5
*pmax = 128
```

But the real file is:

> P2
>
> 5 4
>
> 128

I wanted my output to be as the one before, but then I got:

```
*pm = 0
*pn = 0
*pmax = 0
```

What went wrong?

Comment: You need to skip the 'P2' at the beginning. Try using `fscanf(file, "\n")` before reading the integers.

Comment: You should really show your declarations and initializations of `pn`, `pm` and `pmax`.  Using `&(*pn)` is an obscure way of writing `pn`.

Comment: That's what you get for not testing the return value of fscanf, which gives you the number of successfully converted items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file starts

```
P2
```

with a letter, not a digit. Thus the `fscanf` calls all fail to convert the input to an integer, consuming no input.

You should always check the return value of the `scanf` family of functions to catch conversion failures due to malformed input or corrupted streams.

You can skip the first line with, for example,

```
fscanf(file, "%*[^\n]");
```

Comment: @ThiG. You can also declare a sufficiently large buffer and call `fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, file);`. Or if you know how long the first line is, `fseek(file, line_length, SEEK_SET);`. There are probably a lot of other ways, but somehow, you must move past the first line to start scanning from the second on.

Comment: +1 This is a fairly solid answer. When `fscanf` fails due to read failure, stop processing. When `fscanf` fails due to conversion failure, discard a line using the code at the end of this answer, print a message that indicates "Invalid input. Try again..." and try again.

Answer (score 2):

It's trying to read an `int`, but getting `P`. Since that can't convert to `int`, it's left in the stream, and the conversion fails. The same happens for the second and third numbers.

Rereading your input, you probably want to do something like reading a string, then attempting to convert that to an int. You could read with `%s`, then convert with `strtol`. If that doesn't convert, ignore it and try again.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *inputString(FILE* fp, size_t size){
//The size is extended by the input with the value of the provisional
    char *str;
    int ch;
    size_t len = 0;
    str = realloc(NULL, sizeof(char)*size);//size is start size
    if(!str)return str;
    while(EOF!=(ch=fgetc(fp)) && isspace(ch));//skip space chars
    ungetc(ch, fp);
    while(EOF!=(ch=fgetc(fp)) && !isspace(ch)){
        str[len++]=ch;
        if(len==size){
            str = realloc(str, sizeof(char)*(size+=16));
            if(!str)return str;
        }
    }
    str[len++]='\0';

    return realloc(str, sizeof(char)*len);
}

enum {false, true };

int readInt(FILE *fp, int *n){
    char *token, *endp;
    long wk;

    for(;;){
        token = inputString(fp, 16);//separated by space character
        if(!*token){//EOF
            free(token);
            return false;
        }
        wk = strtol(token, &endp, 0);
        if(*endp=='\0')break;//success read int
        free(token);
    }
    *n = (int)wk;
    free(token);
    return true;
}

int main(void){
    FILE *file;
    int n, m, max,i;

    n = m = max = 0;
    file = fopen("filename.txt", "r");
    readInt(file, &n);
    readInt(file, &m);
    readInt(file, &max);
/*
    printf("debug:");
    if(readInt(file, &i)==false){
        printf("false\n");
    }
*/
    fclose(file);

    printf("m = %d\n", m);
    printf("n = %d\n", n);
    printf("max = %d\n", max);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe a little ridiculous.

Comment: Redefining the identifiers true/false as enums is a bad idea since C99.